# Undefined array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I get an " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " at line 26. I can't see the reason this is happening, because the console logs line 24 as an array with a value at index 1, but line 25 logs as undefined.

```
"use strict"
function findpath(G,si,di){
    //G is an array of nodes (with id, lat, lon)
    var P=[si];
    var C=[0,P];
    var M=[C];
    var O=[];
    var ctr=0;
    var done = false;
    var reached = false;
    var best = undefined;


    while(!done){
        ctr++;
        if( ctr > 100 ){
            alert("Sorry, can't find the destination.");
            return P;
        }

        for (var i=0;i<M.length;++i){
            console.log(P);
            console.log(C);
            console.log(M[i]);
            console.log(M[i[0]]);
            var last = M[i[1]].length;
            var v = M[i[1[last]]];

            //select a random neighbor...
            if( v.N.length === 0 ){
                alert("Wat?");
                return [];
            }
            else if( v.N.length === 1 ){
                break;
            }
            else if( v === di ){
                break;
            }
            else {
                for (var j=0;j<v.N.length;++j){
                    var temp = M[i];
                    O.push(temp[1].push(v.N[j]));
                    var dist = distance(v.lat,v.lon,v.N[j].lat,v.N[j].lon);
                    var temp2 = O.length-1;
                    O[temp2[0]]+=dist;
                    if (v.N[j]===di){
                        reached = true;
                        if (best === undefined){
                            console.log("ASSIGN");
                            best = O[temp2];
                        }
                        else {
                            if (O[temp2[0]]<best[0]) {
                                best = O[temp2];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        M = O;
        var any = false;
        for (var i=0;i<M.length;++i) {
            if (M[i[0]]<best[0]) {
                any = true;
            }
        }
        if (!any) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    //return the path
    return best[1];
}

function distance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
}
```

Output:

```
Array[1]     findpath.js:22
Array[2]     findpath.js:23
Array[2]
   0: 0
   1: Array[1]
      0: 13
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array[0]
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array[0]     findpath.js:24
undefined findpath.js:25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined    findpath.js:26
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `M[i[0]]` and `M[i[1[last]]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** - per your comments, it looks like you have an array of arrays, and that, if I understand you correctly, `M[i[1]]` should be `M[i][1]`

---

You're checking

```
console.log(M[i[0]]);
```

but then accessing

```
 var last = M[i[1]].length;
```

it seems as though `M[i[0]]` contains a valid array, but `M[i[1]]` does not.

I would recommend taking a closer look at your `M`, and `i` arrays to figure out why `M[i[1]]` is undefined.

---

Edit, as the comment below says, `i` appears to be the loop control variable.  Did you mean to type simply `M[i]` ?

Comment: `i` is the loop counter not an array

Comment: The problem is that `console.log(M[i]);` returns the contents as `0` in the 0 index, and an array in the 1 index, but both `M[i[0]]` and `M[i[0]]` come back as undefined.

Comment: @iwhitt567 - if `i` is an integer, then `M[i[0]]` is simply invalid.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: In total, M is an array of arrays, and each of those arrays contain an integer as well as another array. Array[Array[0,Array[]]]

Comment: What I'm trying to do is access the i'th array within M, and then the contents in that inner array.

Comment: @iwhitt567 - I *think* I see - check out my last edit.  Bottom line is that if `i` is an integer, then `i[1]` will never be valid, let alone `M[i[1]]`.

Comment: Edit: I don't know why I thought this was the proper syntax. I need M[i][1], and so on. I think perhaps I need to walk away and come back tomorrow. Thank you for your input.